# What is the meaning of the title of Fruits Basket?

Tags: fruits-basket

The title of "Fruits Basket" seems to imply that there is some basket with fruits in it which is somehow relevant to the story. However, I imagine that a story about a literal basket of fruits would not be very interesting.

What is the significance of the title? Is it referencing a literal basket of fruits or is it symbolizing something else?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Fruits Basket is a game where a player is assigned to one fruit (any fruit as long as it is a fruit). Tohru was assigned by her friends to be the onigiri (rice ball, which obviously isn't a fruit), so she was left sitting alone because onigiri won't be called since onigiri isn't a fruit. It is also a metaphor on how Tohru can't belong to the Souma family as an onigiri won't belong to a Fruits Basket. [Reference here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fruit_Basket_Turnover#References_to_the_game).

Answer (score 4):

The fruits basket is metaphorical, not literal. It represents how Tohru feels like an outsider in her family, at school and with the Sohmas, in the same way that an onigiri doesn't belong in a fruits basket. In the manga, she is often represented as an onigiri.

Answer (score 0):

It is a reference to a Tohru played in her childhood where everyone is given a name of a fruit. However, some of the kids, who were pretty mean to her, labelled her as a rice ball (onigiri) so the name of her "fruit" was never called out and she wasn't able to participate. This also symbolizes how isolated she was as a child. Also, in the manga, sometimes when one of the 12 zodiac speak, you can see a small picture of their specific animal when their face isn't in the panel. In Tohru's case, we see a small picture of a rice ball instead.

Comment: Welcome to Anime.SE! I'm afraid I don't really see how this differs from the accepted answer from seven years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Some anime titles are literally meaningless, however fruits basket is not one without meaning.

Tohru is like an outcast, fruits basket is like a musical chairs game, except it uses fruit names and Japanese kids play it. 
In this anime, Tohru is like outcast by the group and called onigiri (not a fruit), and thus she was left out.

Thus the title would seem to be about how Tohru is different or outcast, and maybe finds her happiness with different people.

[Fruits Basket game](https://genkienglish.net/fruitbasket.htm)

Comment: Welcome to Anime.SE! I'm afraid I don't really see how this differs from the accepted answer from seven years ago.